# container width error in bootstrap custom css

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to make background video for the website. Whatever I am doing there is a gap in the top and left sides. I changed the width left position anyway the error still is same. Please find the print screen from the website. I also attached my CSS and HTML code. Thank you for reading.

CSS:

```
 header-container {
    width: 90%;
    height: 900px;
    border-left: 1%;
    border-right: none;
    position: relative;
    padding: 20px;
}

.video-container {
    top: 0%;
    left: 0%;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

video {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    width: 100%;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="header-container">
<div class="video-container">
 <video preload="true" autoplay = "autoplay" loop = "loop" muted>
    <source src="video/test.mp4" type="video/mp4" >
    </video>
 </div>
</div>
```

https://ibb.co/incNY5

Comment: not seeing it. http://codepen.io/mcoker/pen/XRZKoX

Comment: it a same except opacity and this is for transparency. But still same as in picture which I shared

Comment: Sorry, not following you. I put the code you provided in the codepen that I linked to and I don't see gaps in the top or left.

Comment: I will be crazy. Why there is a gap in there. I checked the whole CSS maybe I repeated that, but no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `padding` in `heading-container`. Set it 0px.

Comment: Thanks, I set padding to zero, too. But the same I also think that it will be from padding but no.

Comment: This was from padding. I fixed. Thanks